Is hyperoperator a generalization of neural network?
We know that artificial neural network (ANN) components are:

$x$: input
$y$: output
$w$: weight
$b$: bias

For example, a single layer of ANN with a linear activation function is basically a linear regression: $$ y=xw+b $$
Using hyperoperator, we can construct the equivalent formula.
$$ y=(x[2]w)[1]b$$
Therefore, a single-unit neuron based on a hyperoperator can be defined as: $$ y=x[k]w $$
Where $k$ as an operator selector, $x,w,y,k$ having the range of $[0,2^n-1]$ where $n$ is the number of bits, and they are all positive integer. $k$ and $w$ are parameters that can be tuned by the optimizer.
It seems the model has linear activation. However, my intuition said it's possible a single neuron has non-linear activation since $k$ can be a parameter that is tuned by the optimizer, especially for $k\geq3$, which is an hyper exponential operator. Thus, it has similarity with KAN, in which the activation is the tunable part
Since they are all positive integers, any continuous floating point can be transformed into integer space. E.g., a normalized $P$ like:
$$
P:[0,1], P \in \mathbb{R}
$$
is analogous to:
$$
P:[0,2^n-1], P \in \mathbb{N_0}
$$
Therefore, it's just scaling and normalization issue when the inputs, outputs, and the weights in real domain.
Actually, it's up to the architect how to define a single layer, like these examples, note we can replace $k$ with indexed $w$ as they are tunnable parameters:

$y=w_0[w_1]w_2$
$y=w_0[w_1]x$
$y=w_0[x]w_1$
$y=w_0[x]x$
$y=x[w_0]w_1$
$y=x[w_0]x$
$y=x[x]w_0$
$y=x[x]x$ (deterministic output)

Hence, to construct a multi-layer neural network, just perform recursivity like these examples:

$y=x[k](...)$
$y=(...)[k]x$
$y=x[...](...)$
$y=x[w_0[k]w_1]x$
$y=x[x[k]x]x$
$y=x[x](...)$
$y=(...)[...](...)$ and so on...

So, is hyperoperator a generalization of neural network?

Perhaps to qualify as an appropriate generalization of the popular and powerful MLPs, such new types of neural networks need to be able to do stable first order gradient descent optimization which is scalable with big training dataset.
However, since your proposed operator selector $k$ is a discrete parameter, optimizing over $k$ introduces challenges in training, for example, gradient-based methods struggle with discrete optimization. In addition, the interpretability of such networks becomes harder as $k$ grows, and large $k$ will obviously introduce numerical instability which impacts convergence of your proposed neural network's training.
Finally hyperoperators sequence allowed Goodstein to rigorously express and study numerical growth beyond exponentiation (similar to the Ackermann function), and Goodstein's theorem ultimately highlighted the incompleteness limitation of Peano Arithmetic (PA) which cannot prove that every Goodstein sequence eventually terminates at 0, but the same can be proved in the stronger second order arithmetic or ZFC. Therefore the hyperoperators dealing with large number growth are better suited for theoretical edge case studies, but not for the everyday applications target by common ML models. Comparatively speaking, your referenced KANs may have better application since KANs have much less neurons to achieve similar performance of MLPs due to the famous Kolmogorov-Arnold representation theorem linking multivariate/univariate real-valued continuous functions.

The optimizer is not only about gradient descent. It can also be possible to solve it by quantum computing for the optimization problem. Put $k$ and $w$ in superposition so that it explores possible values, and let the system evolve, finding the optimized parameter based on input-output pairs.

I don't see quantum computing is in OP's scope at all, which is yet to become applicable or relevant for everyday ML apps in the near future. Also bear in mind quantum computing as a new and potentially extremely efficient computational technique in some cases don't change computability or incompleteness edge case.

Same for the gradient descent, which implies the question has an agnostic optimizer method.
